# Can Visual Studio Code provide live previews of R Notebooks?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, markdown, rstudio

I use Visual Studio Code for everything aside from generating reports with `R Markdown`. For that, I still use RStudio. When I am trying out some new code and exploring data, I usually use an `R Notebook` file. The killer feature for me is being able to preview it: I can add some text and some code and see how it will look like in the HTML file **without** having to knit it all over. My understanding is that, as of 2021, that is main difference between R notebooks and "plain" R Markdown files.

I prefer VS Code over RStudio any day but I miss that preview feature. Every time I need to see how simple modifications I did on the .Rmd file look on the HTML file, I have to knit it. Currently, I am using Yuke Ueda's R extension for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r

My question for the community is: is there a way to enable the same preview capabilities of RStudio on VS Code? Essentially, I would like to see changes I did on the .Rmd file be reflected on the `.nb.html` file as soon as I save the .Rmd, as in RStudio. Thanks!

Comment: I am very interested in an answer for this question. Please tell If you found It.

Comment: As of October 2022, I have not found the answer and I believe that it's not possible yet.